# Custom function in suitelet's client script for SuiteScript 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am using NetSuite's SuiteScript 2.0 & currently I am working on Suitelet Forms. I have a case in which I am adding a button on my Suitelet form by using `Form.addButton({id:'search',label:'Search',functionName:'customSubmit'});`

I have attached a custom client function i.e. `'customSubmit'` on my Suitelet form button. I want to get & set some Form field values in my `'customSubmit'` function, is there any way in SuiteScript 2.0 through which I can do this.

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Received the working solution from NetSuite support, it says..

I would suggest you to use currentRecord module in your client script. Please be informed that the currentRceord module is not documented yet in the help article. However, we already have a defect (387882) for this and is the module will be available in 2016.2 help article.

Please find the code snippet below.

```
/**
*@NApiVersion 2.0
*@NScriptType ClientScript
*/
define(["N/currentRecord"], function(currentRecord){
        var pageInit = function(context) { } //just to add an entry point

        var customSubmit = function(context) {
            var val = currentRecord.getValue({fieldId: 'field_id1'}); 
            currentRecord.setValue({fieldId: 'field_id2', value: val});
        }
    return {
            pageInit: pageInit,
        customSubmit: customSubmit
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your customSubmit function will execute as client side script.  So just write it as if you are creating a client side script for NetSuite.